# How to batch rename files to 3-digit numbers?

Tags: matlab, file, batch-file, rename, alphanumeric

I apologize in advance that this question is not specific. But my goal is to take a bunch of image files, which are currently named as: 0.tif, 1.tif, 2.tif, etc... and rename them just as numbers to 000.tif, 001.tif, 002.tif, ... , 010.tif, etc...

The reason I want to do this is because I am trying to load the images into matlab and for batch processing but matlab does not order them correctly. I use the dir command as `dir(*.tif)` to get all the images and load them into an array of files that I can iterate over and process, but in this array element 1 is 0.tif, element 2 is 1.tif, element 3 is 10.tif, element 4 is 100.tif, and so on.

I want to keep the ordering of the elements as I process them. However, I do not care if I have to change the order of the elements BEFORE processing them (i.e. I can make it work to rename, for example, 2.tif to 10.tif if I had to) but I am looking for a way to convert the file names the way I initially described.

If there is a better way to get matlab to properly order the files when it loads them into the array using `dir` please let me know because that would be much easier.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are there any integers missing in the sequence? If not you can look for the largest number in the directory and then construct the paths sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without having to rename the files, if you want. When you grab the files using `dir`, you'll have a list of files like so:

```
files = 
   '0.tif'
   '1.tif'
   '10.tif'
   ...
```

You can grab just the numeric part using `regexp`:

```
nums = regexp(files,'\d+','match');
nums = str2double([nums{:}]);
nums =
   0 1 10 11 12 ...
```

`regexp` returns its matches as a cell-array, the second line converts it back to actual numbers.

We can now get an actual numeric order by sorting the resulting array:

```
[~,order] = sort(nums);
```

and then put the files in the correct order:

```
files = files(order);
```

This *should* (I haven't tested it, I don't have a folder full of numerically labelled files handy) produce a list of files like so:

```
files=
   '0.tif'
   '1.tif'
   '2.tif'
   '3.tif'
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is partially dependent on the version of matlab you have. If you have a version with `findstr` this should work well

```erlang
num_files_to_rename = numel(name_array);

for ii=1:num_files_to_rename
    %in my test i used cells to store my strings you may need to
    %change the bracket type for your application
    curr_file = name_array{ii};

    %locates the period in the file name (assume there is only one)
    period_idx = findstr(curr_file ,'.');

    %takes everything to the left of the period (excluding the period)
    file_name = str2num(curr_file(1:period_idx-1));

    %zeropads the file name to 3 spaces using a 0
    new_file_name = sprintf('%03d.tiff',file_name)

    %you can uncomment this after you are sure it works as you planned
    %movefile(curr_file, new_file_name);
end
```

the actual rename operation `movefile` is commented out for now. make sure the output names are as you expect before uncommenting it and renaming all the files.

**EDIT** there is no real error checking in this code, it just assumes every file name has one and only one period, and an actual number as the name

Comment: Instead of using `findstr`, you could use `fileparts`.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below do the rename of the files you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B *.tif') do (
   set "name=00%%~Nf"
   ren "%%f" "!name:~-3!.tif"
)
```

Note that this solution preserve *the same order* of your original files, even if there are missing numbers in the sequence..